# Tool to check the database in Production

Tags: database, select

I Would like to use a tool to execute SELECT requests on the PRODUCTION database. This tool must be full security because my site is deployed on Internet.

Any idea ?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can try use:

1. MySQL WorkBench or other MySQL Client program;
2. SSH to the Server and connect from the command prompt;
3. Use PHPMyAdmin (make sure to password protect and set the right configuration);

If you are really in need of an extra level of security you may want to consider setting up a VPN between your computer and the server where MySQL is running.